# Forgin/Buiilding TCP packets in ANSI C

Tags: c, tcp, network-programming, packet, c89

How do I, without using third-party tools, craft TCP (and even UDP for that matter) packets in ANSI C? I want to be able to set all option flags, source ip address etc. So full control. Haven't found any good text about it online. Or I'm just using the wrong search criteria.

Comment: It's not a complete code example to describe it all, but I found this now for all interested: http://www.tenouk.com/Module42a.html. Look under "Raw vs Coocked socket". But if anyone has more info and code examples please write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I started cooking raw sockets on my own, I found [Beej's](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/) guide to network programming as valuable as venerable Stevens "TCP/IP Illustrated" books serie.